# Extraction of pixel values in lines to each number of pixels

Tags: r, spatial, raster

In my example I create a raster:

```
require(raster); require(sp) 
## Raster Raster creation
r <- raster(nc=10, nr=10)
r <- setValues(r, round(runif(ncell(r))* 255))
```

After, I make pixels values extraction by selection of coordinates:

```
x     <- c(-150)
y     <- c(-80)
p <- data.frame(x,y)
pontos <- SpatialPoints(p)

p$cel <- cellFromXY(r, pontos)
p$col <- colFromCell(r, p$cel)
p$row <- rowFromCell(r, p$cel)
p
plot(r)
text(r)
points(pontos, pch = 4, col = 2)
```

But, I'd like to find a way to extract the value of the pixels in which I would select a coordinate and the function would perform the extraction of the pixels of entire horizontal lines of the raster to every two pixels from the given coordinate. For example, I choose xy(-150,-80) coordinates but my function below returns values only for the first line and need lines 4, 7 and 10 too.

```
require(plyr)
vals2cols <- ldply(1:nrow(p),
                   function(ir){
                     getValuesBlock(r, 
                                    col = p$col[ir], 
                                    ncols = 10, 
                                    row = p$row[ir],
                                    nrows = 1)

                   }# end fun
)

df <- data.frame(p, vals2cols)
df
```

This is possible?

Comment: To be honest, I am having a hard time understanding your question. Can you add an examle with an expected output? What do you mean by "coordinates each 2 pixels  .... vertical lines 1,4,7 and 10." ?

Comment: I make my question again, with corrections.